# Do you always have to inherit service variable in controller in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, inheritance

i'm current starting to wrap my head around Angular, and i'm struggling with 2 things:

**The first problem:**
I have an controller 'AboutCtrl', which uses variables from a service 'Abstract'. Now what i want to do is set some basic variables in this service like: 'mobileMenuOpen'.

Now what i want is that 'AboutCtrl' uses the value from 'Abstract', now i've been searching around and i found this way to do it:

```
constructor (private $scope: IAboutScope, $rootScope, Abstract) {
  console.log(Abstract);
  $scope.mobileMenuOpen = Abstract.mobileMenuOpen;
}
```

Now what i'm wondering is, is there a way to automatically inherit all of these variables?

**The second problem:**
Is there a way to display a variable from 'Abstract' service in a view/index.html?

**Example:** in my about view i want to show mobileMenuOpen's value, now when i inherit the variable in the AboutCtrl like shown above it works, but how would i be able to do this without inheritance?

I've done some research about best practise and using services/factory seems best practise, if not some other examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$scope.myAbstract = Abstract` then all the values of your service would be assigned to `myAbstract` and in a template, you can do `{{ myAbstract.mobilemenuOpen }}` or even `ng-click="myAbstract.mobilemenuOpen = !myAbstract.mobilemenuOpen"` to toggle the menu

Comment: Ah perfect thanks! How about without inheritance to display the variable? if you write an answer i'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your service looks like this:

```
.service('abstract', function abstract(){
  this.mobileMenuOpen = false;
  this.someMethod = function(){
    //do the magic
    return 'cowabunga';
  };
})
```

If you assign the service to $scope by reference like this:

```
$scope.myAbstract = abstract
```

then all the values of your service would be assigned to `myAbstract` and accessible in the templates as well, also it will be two-way binded

```
<p> Is the menu open: {{ myAbstract.mobileMenuOpen }} </p>
<p> {{ myAbstract.someMethod() }} was the ninja turtles war cry! </p>
```

Assignment like

```
$scope.mobileMenuOpen = abstract.mobileMenuOpen;
```

Would be assigning it by value so whatever change you make later in service will have no effect on `$scope.mobileMenuOpen`